# What is the "+" in "+filter"?

Tags: css

[This tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/y6lcda) shows a css blur example with

```
img {
    +filter: blur(30px);
}
```

then goes on to mention **"Note: + stands for vendor prefix"**. Why is a plus sign used here instead of a vendor prefix such as "-webkit-"?

Comment: I'm guessing the author didn't want to complicate the samples with 3x statements for each filter?

Comment: @MartyWallace I hadn't considered that. I just spent a lot of time reading the spec assuming it was a new pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's shorthand copied from [this authoritative tutorial site](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/). On HTML5Rocks however they didn't neglect putting the correct hover on there, stating "Please apply relevant vendor prefix".

As such, `+filter` should indeed correctly be written as:

```
filter:blur(30px);
-o-filter:blur(30px); /* rather obsolete since Opera switched to Webkit */
-ms-filter:blur(30px);
-moz-filter:blur(30px);
-webkit-filter:blur(30px);
```

The origin is the [Compass extension to SASS](http://compass-style.org/) which allows this syntax as a real shorthand for vendor specific rules.

As you can see on [this site however](http://caniuse.com/css-filters) only Webkit currently supports filters. As such you can also ignore the `-o-` prefix for features that won't be added to Presto anymore anyway.

Comment: Opera hasn't switched to Webkit yet.  The current stable version still uses Presto according to the UA string:  `Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.15`.

Comment: They aren't adding new features to Presto anymore pending the switch, that's my point. Caniuse.com even lists 'next Opera' as 'requires webkit prefix.